# Removing a Link from the navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

[image]

So I really want to delete the "Departments1" link from the navigation bar but it doesn't have a delete option like the rest of my links.  It has a show/hide but I would rather it not be there at all so that it is more organized.  How would I go about deleting this completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to site settings,  the look and feel - navigation settings - fix it there - this is much more reliable that edit/links on either top nav or quick launch. 
if not using publishing, you should be.

Comment: Thank you and your'e right this is more reliable it seems!